# Scala Akka broadcasting send message to all child actors from Parent Context

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

In my task parent actor create some child actors and send message to them

```
def apply(): Behavior[CreateBranch] = {
     Behaviors.receive { (context, message) =>
        val child1 = context.spawn(Child(), "child1")
        val child2 = context.spawn(Child(), "child2")
        val child3 = context.spawn(Child(), "child3")

        context.children.foreach {
           child ! Child.SomeMessage
      {
  }
}
```

Child actor defined as:

```
object Child {

     sealed trait SomeMessage
     def apply():Behavior[SomeMessage] = {
       // some behaviour
    {
}
```

But expression "context.children" does not work: children defined as Iterable[ActorRef[Nothing]] instead of Iterable[ActorRef[Child.SomeMessage]]

In documentation about "context.children" [ActorContext.children](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/from-classic.html)

"this is not a useful way to lookup children when the purpose is to send messages to them."

And this document suggest alternative way of realisation - but it about of 30 lines of code!

Is there any other alternative way to realise broadcast message send ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in general to guarantee the static type of the child actors (and the same is true of the parent actor and the guardian actor (`context.system`)).

However, if you're absolutely sure that all children will accept the message you can

```scala
context.children.foreach { child =>
  child.unsafeUpcast[Child.SomeMessage] ! Child.SomeMessage
}
```

As the name implies, this is unsafe and allows you to send messages without any guarantee that the child will handle them.  Since the implementation of an Akka Typed `Behavior` involves a classic actor which performs message casts, a mismatch between `Behavior` and `ActorRef` can cause the actor to immediately fail.  `unsafeUpcast` is (at least from the sender's perspective...) safer than an `asInstanceOf` cast, as this at least guarantees that you're actually calling `!` on an `ActorRef`.

Answer (score 0):

You asked "Is there any other alternative way to realise broadcast message send ?".

Levi's answer is the most technically correct. But I think the "real" answer is not to use `context.children`. This complication is caused by the type system trying to protect you from something that is a very legitimate concern. That collection contains ALL children. And there are lots of times I might spawn a child just to monitor a timeout, receive a single message, or some other task that might not understand that message.

If you want to send a specific message to child actors, as was pointed out in Levi's answer, you probably don't really mean "all child actors", you mean "all child actors who understand this message". And although there are some other ways you could do this, I always find it easiest just to maintain your own collection of ActorRefs for an actor of a particular type. If I have "worker actors" I maintain my own sequence and then the message types just work automagically.

My experience is that you should really only use context.children for system-type operations. But anything else, I maintain my own collection. That way if I create a new type of child actor at a later date, I don't break any assumptions I'm making about the type of child actors and what messages they can receive.